# SQL Count/GROUP issue

Tags: sql

Trying to display Company Name, First & Last name where the number of calls is less than 5. This shows which customers have called <5 times and names which company the caller belongs too but i'm looking for which companies have < 5 calls.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N8ni.jpg - Database Tables

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxduc.jpg - Expected Result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk3XW.jpg - My results

```
SELECT Company_name, First_name, Last_name, COUNT(Company_name) as nc
FROM Customer JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref
JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
GROUP by Company_name, First_name, Last_name
HAVING COUNT(Company_name) < 5
```

Comment: So, you need the company name and the first and last name of....who?

Comment: The caller who belongs to the company with less than 5 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove First_Name, Last_Name from the select and group by parts of the query and you'll get what you're asking for (am guessing there may be something further you need but appreciate the contradiction if you only want calls per company but also want each of the callers first and last names somehow associated with it i.e. that info os at different groupings)

```
SELECT Company_name, COUNT(Company_name) as nc 
FROM Customer JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id 
GROUP by Company_name
HAVING COUNT(Company_name) < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this... 
In a subquery, find the companies you are interested in. Then get the people from that company who have called.

(I haven't tested this so it might not be exact, but it should give you an idea)

`SELECT Company_name, First_name, Last_name
FROM Customer 
   JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref 
   JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id 
WHERE Company_name in 
   (SELECT Company_name
    FROM Customer 
    JOIN Caller ON Customer.Company_ref = Caller.Company_ref
    JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id
    GROUP by Company_name
    HAVING COUNT(Company_name) < 5)`